# How to Add to an unknown List property of an object at runtime?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, properties, gettype

I have a 'Profile' object/class with an IList of 'Addresses', of which, I will only know their type [profile / addresses] at runtime via GetType() / GetProperties() etc., though I wish to .Add to this list e.g.:

```
var profile = session.Get<ProfileRecord>(1);

dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj = profile;
obj["Addresses"].Add(addressNew);
```

This does not work due to:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'Test.Models.ProfileRecord'.

I've been looking at IDictionary, but have been unsuccessful in my attempts, nor even know if I should be heading down that path - so what is the correct way to go about this? This entire concept is new to me, so please don't over assume my capabilites ;) Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` or `ExpandoObject` in the first place?

Can't you just write `profile.Addresses.Add(addressNew)`?

Comment: If you do want runtime disptach simply change `var profile =` into `dynamic profile =`. The ExpandoObject you create is immediately overwritten anyway so it's pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this if you dont know the type of profile.

```
var prop = profile.GetType().GetProperty("Addresses").GetValue(profile);
prop.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(prop, new object[] {1}); // Add the Value to the list
```

But then you must be sure the List is already initalized.

But i think you should be able to cast your object and set the Property directly like:

```
if(profile.GetType == typeof (ProfileRecord))
{
    var record = (ProfileRecord)profile;
    if (profile.Addresses == null)
    {
         profile.Addresses = new List<Address>();
    }

    prfile.Addresses.Add(addressNew);
}
```